# How to use tabbed activity in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

So I have this little code that is supposed to open me a tabbed layout:

```
public class FriendsList extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText search;
   ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    Activity activity=this;
    CallbackManager callbackManager=null;
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // show the given tab
        }
@Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // hide the given tab
        }
@Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // probably ignore this event
        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends_list);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);

       actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                            .setTabListener(tabListener));
        }
```

The problem is that the second I start the app, it crashes. But when I remove the actionBar references it works perfectly. There is no logcat when it crashes as this is my default application. If necessary I can share my manifest and the rest of the code.

Thanks in Advance

UPDATE:
Logcat;

```
 ss: com.inc.nicky.messengersayit, PID: 14114
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.inc.nicky.messengersayit/com.inc.nicky.messengersayit.FriendsList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:70)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:141)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:29)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:93)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:429)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:77) 
            at com.inc.nicky.messengersayit.FriendsList.<init>(FriendsList.java:58)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invo
```

Comment: "The problem is that the second I start the app, it crashes" -- please post the stack trace. "There is no logcat when it crashes as this is my default application" -- there is always a stack trace when your application crashes.

Comment: I added it as an update. I am terribly sorry for the delay! Hope you have any ideas what it might be.
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never call methods that you inherit from component base classes (e.g., `AppCompatActivity`) from a data member initializer. Wait until `onCreate()`, and specifically after `super.onCreate()`.

IOW, you cannot call `getSupportActionBar()` where you are. Do not call that until `super.onCreate()` returns.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It works perfectly now! You are God!